# React linter warning: unused state field -- while the state field is being used in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have an array of times in state I use to calculate an average time, also in state.

```
this.state = {
  avgTime: null,
  allTimes: []
}
```

then the method to do the calculation:

```
this.getTime = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const timeDelta = Date.now() - this.state.startTime;
    prevState.allTimes.push(timeDelta);
    const factor = 10 ** -1;
    const avgTime = Math.round((prevState.allTimes.reduce((a, b) => a + b) /
      prevState.allTimes.length) * factor) / factor;
    return {
      avgTime,
      allTimes: prevState.allTimes,
    }
  })
}
```

My linter is warning me that allTimes is an unused state field, even though I use it in setState.

That leads me to believe this is a bad practice, but I'm not sure why.  Is this something I should refactor, or just drop a linter exception and move on?

Comment: This warning means that it's not being used in a way that impacts the component. You can set the state all you want, but if your render method makes no use of it, it's labeled an unused state field. It looks like you only use the previous state of `allTimes` so that makes sense

Comment: Uses inside `setState` aren't considered in this cases. If you use it only on `setState` it doesn't need to be at the component's state at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linter warns you because you are not using this state in any of your components. First time I encountered that I got confused too. But when I think a little bit more it seemed right. Since, why am I creating a state and even us setState if I am not using it?

So, creating and setting state fires a warning if you are not using it.